# Is there a way to manually separate the distance between 2 lines so that it is represented better?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, symbology

I work with powerlines and there are too many lines quite close to each other making it look line one thick line when zoomed out . Obviously they do separate out when zoomed in but most of the time we need to work at a zoomed out level

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You have a tag for ArcGIS 10.1 but are you using ArcMap at that version?

Comment: Representations will do that but I think that is only available in 10.3 and above.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm